Kendo Chart date not converted correctly it's in GMT which needs to be UTC & also in correct sirt
To properly format your heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsDataSource and ensure that dates are correctly handled as UTC, here's the full implementation:

Define the toDate function to parse and return dates as UTC.
Use Kendo's timezone.convertUTC to ensure dates are treated as UTC in the schema's parse function.

toDate Function: The toDate function parses the date from the provided string and returns a JavaScript Date object.

Schema Parse Function: Each timestamp in the response is converted to UTC using kendo.timezone.convertUTC.

Chart Configuration:

The categoryAxis labels and tooltips use new Date(value) to ensure the date is correctly interpreted as a UTC date.

The tooltip template correctly formats the date as MM/dd/yyyy.

This ensures that dates are correctly handled as UTC throughout your data processing and chart rendering, preventing any time zone-related issues.

/*********************************code *********************************/

function toDate(value) {
    var dateRegExp = /^\/Date\((.*?)\)\/$/;
    var date = dateRegExp.exec(value);
    return new Date(parseInt(date[1], 10)); // Directly parse the timestamp
}

/************* Datasource ******************************************/

var heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function () {
                return '@Url.Action("GetHeatExchangerSurveyCalculations", "Dashboard")';
            },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            sort: { field: "year", dir: "asc" },
            type: "POST"
        },
        parameterMap: dataSourceParameterMap
    },
    requestStart: function () {
        heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsLoading = true;
        requestStart();
    },
    requestEnd: function () {
        heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsLoading = false;
        onRequestEnd();
    },
    group: {
        field: "Name"
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (i, v) {
                v.TimeStamp = kendo.timezone.convertUTC(toDate(v.TimeStamp));
            });
            return response;
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
        onError("#skinTempChart");
        onError("#WaterVelocityChart");
        onError("#HeatFluxChart");
        onError("#WaterFlowDataChart");
        onError("#UCoefficientChart");
    }
});

/**************************Chart Binding*************************/

function onContentLoad(e) {
    var skinTempChart = $("#skinTempChart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Skin Temp",
            visible: false
        },
        legend: {
            position: "top"
        },
        dataBound: function (e) {
            setColors("#skinTempChart");
            onNoData(e, "#skinTempChart");
        },
        dataSource: heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsDataSource,
        sortable: true,
        autoBind: false,
        series: [
            {
                type: "line",
                categoryField: "TimeStamp",
                field: "SkinTemp",
                name: "#= group.value #",
                axis: "temp",
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "${ kendo.toString(value, 'n0')}" + "</br>" + " ${ kendo.toString(new Date(category), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}"
                },
            }
        ],
  

Schema Parse Function: Each timestamp in the response is converted to UTC using kendo.timezone.convertUTC.
Chart Configuration:
The categoryAxis labels and tooltips use new Date(value) to ensure the date is correctly interpreted as a UTC date.
The tooltip template correctly formats the date as MM/dd/yyyy.
This ensures that dates are correctly handled as UTC throughout your data processing and chart rendering, preventing any time zone-related issues.
Error while date conversion its show GMT not UTC
